# Counting Datediff between 2 rows from 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table as below.

Somehow I want to calculate the idle time between End Date and Start Date.

Example: Idle time between 11:38:30 with 11:40:08, 11:49:35 with 12:00:19.

The problem is the station index number 5. It has a null value in 2 columns so I want to  calculate base on the previous row

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome Cong. SQL Server, mysql or...? And posted data always beats image

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one value for each station, than grouping will work:

```
select 
    StationIndex, 
    max(Statoin_End_Date) - min(Station_Start_Date) as Duration
from table_name
group by StationIndex
```

Otherwise please explain logic in greater details.

Comment: Could it be possible to calculate the time between 11:38:30 with 11:40:08 in the table above? Thank you.

Comment: @CongHoaNguyen not sure what you mean by that question. Do you need all rows between specified time values? If so, it is a simple WHERE condition: where Station_End_Date between '11:38:30' and '11:40:08'

Comment: yes, I want to calculate all the rows in the table with an idea like that (11:38:30 with 11:40:08 and continue). Because I'm working with more values than the value appears in the table so I need another statement which can fulfill my idea.

Comment: @CongHoaNguyen I'm sorry, I'm still not clear about the question. If you want to filter based on row, you should use WHERE condition. If you need to filter based on Station, you should group based on station and filter based on HAVING condition.

Comment: it should be like this: calculate the idle time for 2 rows in the table (you can see) example =>
11:38:30 with 11:40:08,
11:49:35 with 12:00:19,
12:03:51 with 12:05:08,
.... etc
because I'm working with a table with 300.000 rows so it impossible for me to type one by one.

Comment: If all data is similar to example, only 2 rows per station, than my script should give you duration of idle. Otherwise, if you have multiple rows per station with multiple idle periods, it will be really hard to do in sql. So if my script doesn't provide you with required answer, please add more complecated example of data and add desired example of output. Plus add examples of scripts you tried that didn't work for you.